# Trash can exists but no file will delete because there is no folder for trash. "Unable to find or create trash"

Tags: trash

The trash folder has obviously been deleted. How can I restore the trash so that I can delete files?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/491953/15811

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it would be remotely "easy" to delete a trash folder, at least without a sudo command, and even then.  Assuming you believe someone else did this, you might want to be more concerned with who is messing with your computer, and why!  I would guess the person who did this was either trying to forcibly delete your trash or recover files from it.  In either case it is cause for concern.

If you haven't rebooted, I strongly recommend this option before trying to replace something that might not actually be missing.  However if you wish to reveal the trashcan without rebooting, I may have a solution.

In my Ubuntu installation, the location of the actual trashcan file is HIDDEN within the home folder as follows:

```
/home/[user]/.Trash-0
```

To see all the invisible files as well as your "*.Trash-0*" folder, please navigate to your home folder in BASH and at the command line type:

```
ls -a
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating the folder by 
 `mkdir /home/UserName/.local/share/Trash`

Comment: I think you'll find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/491953/682481) might work better.