# Failing to configure automount on ntf partition on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, automount, trash

let me give some context:

I have a dual booting system (ubuntu 20.04 + Windows 10, over UEFI). Both SOs in the same disk (ssd nvme on m.2 port). Additionally a have a shared partition (same disk) with NTFS file system. I use this shared partition as common place to save Documents, Pics, etc, in both SOs symlinks (Documents, Pics, etc) are point to this partition. I disable fastboot on Windows 10, and boot systems start normally.

The problem appear when I try to use the shared partition on Ubuntu. If configure it to auto mount then Ubuntu "is'n unable to find or create Trash folder". On the other hand, if I mount it manually after startup, the file explorer and other apps work a little strange. I also has a HDD (on sata port) with NTFS and it work without issues (perfect automount and can send files to trash), both has exactly the same config.

I google this issue (unable to find trash folder) and follow the different suggestions without results. The majority of suggestion could be resume on this treath : [Unable to find or create trash directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262817/unable-to-find-or-create-trash-directory)

Any suggestion or ideas about that ?

- I am using gnome-disks to configure it (to prevent broken the partition)

**Edit**: Output of `cat /etc/fstab` for *manual-mount* (**Without** trash issues)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation

UUID=c034e0e6-a237-47fe-a1e1-419cd036aeea /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
#UUID=29AB-CF8D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /windows was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation

UUID=1B109D6E67D5A46C /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0

# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation

UUID=0be4f712-932c-4243-8b93-fbeb7618593a none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=29AB-CF8D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab` for *automount* (**With** trash issues)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation

UUID=c034e0e6-a237-47fe-a1e1-419cd036aeea /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
#UUID=29AB-CF8D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /windows was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation

UUID=1B109D6E67D5A46C /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0

# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation

UUID=0be4f712-932c-4243-8b93-fbeb7618593a none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=29AB-CF8D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/C0E810DBE810D190 /mnt/C0E810DBE810D190 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: As in that thread, post your fstab. `cat /etc/fstab`. If not automounting with fstab, you then have to manually mount everytime. Also make sure Windows fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Windows Fast Startup is off. The partition could be automount, but with the "can find or create trash folder" issue.

Comment: What settings in fstab? Post this: `cat /etc/fstab`. Some suggestions: For ntfs UUID shown is example only see below:
`UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /media/WinD ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20) 
uid=1000 should fix the trash problems as well:

Comment: Sorry, format errors posting `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: You were right the `nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0` combination works perfectly with `automount` option. No more problems with trash folder or failing to automount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *oldfred* comment the `nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0` combination works perfectly with `automount` option. No more problems with trash folder or failing to automount on startup. Apparently `windows_names 0 0` was the missing command